# Как нарисовать блок-схему преобразования выбранных литералов Java в десятичную систему

Tags: java, блок-схема, литерал

Предположим, что вход содержит строку одного из следующих символов:
«0», за которым следуют 99 цифр (восьмеричное кодирование числа)
«0x», за которым следуют 98 цифр (шестнадцатеричное число)
«0b», за которым следуют 98 цифр (кодирование двоичного числа)
Мы загружаем входной символ за символом. На схеме должен быть представлен алгоритм преобразования из распознанной системы в десятичную, поэтому сначала нужно распознать систему, в которой записано число, затем преобразовать его. Однако надо быть осторожны с шестнадцатеричной системой, потому что здесь появляются значения A, B, C, D, E, F, означающие 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 соответственно. Например, 0x000 (... здесь 90 нулей...) 0003D переводится как 3 * 16 + 13 = 61.

Можно сделать условный блок "какой знак х?", с возможностью того, что из такого блока выйдет более 2-х вариантов (т.е. вместо "Д/Н" может быть например, "A/B/C/D/E/F").

Comment: я  не понял  про рисование блок  схемы.  Все остальное решается  через  специальные  методы  класса Integer .     
     s.toBinaryString( какое  то  число);
     s.toHexString(какое -то число);
     s.toOctalString(какое то число);  предварительно  можно проверить  явялется ли  вводное  значение числом

Comment: Спасибо, но дело в том, что нельзя это использовать. Задачу нужно решить используя стандартные арифметические действия, т.е определив что это двоичная система исчислений (0b...), число которое введет пользователь (напр. 0b01110101) нужно перевести в десятичную, т.е 0*2ˆ‎0 + 1*2ˆ‎1 + 1*2ˆ‎2....

Comment: А проблема в построении блок-схемы заключается в том, что нужно запомнить каждое число введенное после 0b и возводить его в степень от 0 до 98 (в зависимости сколько символов введет пользователь после 0b)

Comment: Т.е.  пользователь  вводит  шестнацатиричное,  мыдолжны  узнать что  оно шестнадцатиричное(точно  узнать) и  нам сначала надо  все преобразовать  в  десятичную  систему и затем пишем ..  А  что можно использовать  строки и стримы можно? Тею взять первые  два  символа строки-  узнаь какая  система  исчесления ,  затем  разбить  все  числа на массисв  чисел  и  потом  преобразовам строки  в  числа провести  операцию ,  но проблема  с  буквами обозначающими цифры. при этом мы продолжаем работь со стоками

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "0x99999999999999999999999999999999999999ACCDD9FDAFD99";
        String s1 = s.substring(2); 
        int  base =0;         
        if (s1.substing(0,2).startWitn("0b")) {
          base=2;
        } else if (s1.substing(0,2).startsWith("0X")) {
           base =16;   
        } else  if 90{}/// восьмиричная или какая другая 

        String [] buf = s1.split("{1}");
        int  [] result = new  int [buf.length];
         for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
              switch (buf[i]) {
            case "A":
                 result[i] =10; 
            break;
            case "B":
                 result[i] =11; 
            break;
            case "C":
                 result[i] =12; 
            break;
            case "D":
                 result[i] =13; 
            break;
            case "E":
                 result[i] =14; 
            break;
            case "F":
                 result[i] =15; 
            break;
                
            default:
                 result[i]=Integer.valueOf(buf[i]).intValue(); 
                break;
            }                           
        }
        
        StringBuffer sb =  new StringBuffer(); 
        int reverse = result.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            
            sb.append(result[i] * Math.pow(base,reverse--)).append(",");

        //  sb.append(result[i] * 16^reverse--).append(",");
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
            
        }
```

Или вообще ничего нелья использовать кроме математических  операций?
Тогда только цикл   перемножения числа